# Using MS Access SQL - how would I select the top 5 food items by group (restaurant) based on the number of orders?

Tags: sql, ms-access

[Relationship Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O84Bs.png)

What I want to be able to do is return a query that shows the top 5 items/products on the menu for each of the 3 restaurants in the dataset. I've attached an example of the relationship diagram for some more context. The columns I would like to see in the query are:

1. RestaurantName
2. ItemName
3. NumberofOrders (alias column)

This is what I have at the moment but it doesn't work as expected for the top 5.

```
SELECT RestaurantName, ItemName, COUNT(Orders.OrderNumber) AS NumberofOrders
FROM ((((Restaurants INNER JOIN 
Orders ON Restaurants.RestID = Orders.RestID) INNER JOIN 
OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderNumber=OrderDetails.OrderNumber) INNER JOIN 
Products ON OrderDetails.ItemID = Products.ItemID) INNER JOIN
FoodType ON Products.ProdTypeID = FoodType.ProdType)
WHERE ItemName IN 
(SELECT TOP 5 ItemName 
FROM Products
WHERE ItemName IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY RestaurantName, ItemName
ORDER BY COUNT(Orders.OrderNumber) DESC;
```

This just repeats the same 5 items across all the restaurants. Any point in the right direction would be awesome.

EDIT 1:

Based on a response I got yesterday, I have made some amendments to the code. This the query is returning the full list, as though ignoring the top 5 in the subquery. I can see all the items are sorted by Total Orders (I have also changed the formula for this) Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

```
    SELECT RestaurantName, ItemName, SUM(Quantity)*COUNT(Orders.OrderNumber) AS TotalOrders
FROM ((((Restaurants INNER JOIN 
Orders ON Restaurants.RestID = Orders.RestID) INNER JOIN 
OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderNumber=OrderDetails.OrderNumber) INNER JOIN 
Products ON OrderDetails.ItemID = Products.ItemID) INNER JOIN 
FoodType ON Products.ProdTypeID = FoodType.ProdType)
WHERE ItemName IN 
(SELECT TOP 5 p2.ItemName 
FROM Products AS p2
WHERE p2.ItemName = Products.ItemName
GROUP BY p2.ItemName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
GROUP BY RestaurantName, ItemName
ORDER BY RestaurantName, SUM(Quantity) DESC;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want a correlated subquery:

```
WHERE ItemName IN (SELECT TOP 5 p2.ItemName 
                   FROM Products as p2
                   WHERE p2.RestaurantName = products.RestaurantName
                   GROUP BY p2.ItemName
                   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                  )
```

It seems really odd to me that a table called `products` would have a column called `RestaurantName`.  But you claim that your query works and it has the same reference.

Comment: The table products does not have a column called **RestaurantName** in it. The **WHERE RestaurantName** was meant to be **WHERE ItemName**

Comment: ItemName belongs to Products table and RestaurantName belongs to Restaurants table. Essentially what I am trying to do is bring back the top 5 items based on number of orders placed, but for each restaurant. I am open to all logic changes. When I implement you suggestion I get a pop-up box asking for parameter value. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your filter in the outer `WHERE` is only using the `ItemName` field. For your purpose it should contain both fields.

Like so:

```
SELECT 
  RestaurantName,
  ItemName,
  COUNT(Orders.OrderNumber) AS NumberofOrders
FROM Restaurants 
  INNER JOIN Orders ON Restaurants.RestID = Orders.RestID
  INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderNumber=OrderDetails.OrderNumber
  INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ItemID = Products.ItemID
  INNER JOIN FoodType ON Products.ProdTypeID = FoodType.ProdType
WHERE (RestaurantName, ItemName) IN 
(SELECT TOP 5 RestaurantName, ItemName 
FROM Products
WHERE RestaurantName IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY RestaurantName, ItemName
ORDER BY COUNT(Orders.OrderNumber) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although this returns an 'Exist' error. Any other thoughts?